# Listing composed of multiple "sublistings"

Tags: listings

As a workaround currently I am using framed Verbatim, but I would like that

- this set of listings appear as a single listing in the list of listings
- the codes be rendered by the `listings` package according to my `lstset` settings
- line numbers are shown at the beginning of code lines, but only there, restarting from 1 at each separate file

Is this somehow possible?

My current code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\begin{tabular}{l}
\texttt{config.h} \\
\begin{minipage}{0.78\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
// Choose one of the supported encoding options:
//#define STRING_ENCODING_ASCII
#define STRING_ENCODING_UCS32
//#define STRING_ENCODING_UTF8

#include "rules.h"
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage} \\ \vspace{0.01cm} \\
\texttt{rules.h} \\
\begin{minipage}{0.73\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
#ifdef STRING_ENCODING_UCS32
   #define ENCODING_HEADER "encoding/ucs32.h"
#endif
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage} \\ \vspace{0.01cm} \\
\texttt{text.cpp} \\
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
#include "config.h"
#include ENCODING_HEADER
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{fig:include_macro}The \code{\#include \emph{macropath}} pattern.}
\end{figure}
```

And its result:
[image]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63928/combining-subfloat-and-newfloat-packages-for-sublistings-environment

Comment: Do you need pagebreaks also or you are all right with the "floating" because of the figure environment?

Comment: I am ok without pagebreaks at the moment. I cannot say I will never need them, but it is only a nice to have extra for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517926/latex-how-to-make-listings-subfloats-use-listing-counters-toc-etc) describes a solution based on the `subfig` package, but the latter has compatibility problems with the ubiquitous `hyperref` package (see [Stephan's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13631/21891)) and the `subcaption` package is recommended instead of `subfig`.

Below is my attempt at a solution using `subcaption`. It's not optimal---lacks automation and the vertical spacing between listing and caption is a bit off---but it should get you halfway there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% -----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{filecontents}
% I generate the source files here for completeness of the MWE.
% In practice, those three files should sit in some folder accessible to pdflatex.
\begin{filecontents*}{config.h}
// Choose one of the supported encoding options:
//#define STRING_ENCODING_ASCII
#define STRING_ENCODING_UCS32
//#define STRING_ENCODING_UTF8

#include "rules.h"
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{rules.h}
#ifdef STRING_ENCODING_UCS32
   #define ENCODING_HEADER "encoding/ucs32.h"
#endif
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{text.cpp}
#include "config.h"
#include ENCODING_HEADER
\end{filecontents*}
% -----------------------------------------------

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for filler text

\usepackage{float}          % for defining a new float env. (multilisting)
    \newfloat{multilisting}{tbphH}{lopbl}   
    \floatname{multilisting}{Listing}

\usepackage{subcaption} % for defining a custom subfloat env. (submultilisting)
    \DeclareCaptionSubType{multilisting}
    \captionsetup[submultilisting]
    {
        font            = {tt,normalsize},
        justification   = raggedright,
        singlelinecheck = off,
    }

\usepackage{listings}   
    \lstset
    {
        language    = C++,
        numbers     = left,
        frame       = single,
        captionpos  = b,
    }

\usepackage{hyperref}

% new macro for a bit more automation
\newcommand\sublstinputlisting[2][1]
% 1: multiplying factor of \textwidth;
% 2: path to source file
{
    \begin{submultilisting}[b]{#1\textwidth}
        \lstset
        {
            title           = \lstname,
            captionpos  = t,        
        }
        \lstinputlisting{#2}%
    \end{submultilisting}%
}

% macro code undefined in your incomplete example, so I just coded my own
\newcommand\code[1]{\texttt{#1}}


\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\vfill

\kant[1]
\begin{multilisting}
    \sublstinputlisting[0.85]{config.h}
    \par
    \sublstinputlisting[0.8]{rules.h}
    \par
    \sublstinputlisting[0.45]{text.cpp}
    \captionsetup{type=lstlisting}%
    \caption{The \code{\#include \emph{macropath}} pattern.}
    \label{my_cplusplus_listing}
\end{multilisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = test listing]
test
test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```